# Establish the inequality $e^x \geq 1-\ln (1-x)$ for $x \leq 0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm very confused as to where to start on this one.  I assume I would start with some smaller inequalities then work towards this one with algebraic manipulation but I can't figure out where to start.

Comment: Please be advised the answer you have accepted is incorrect

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**PLEASE NOTE THERE IS AN ISSUE WITH THIS ANSWER AT THE SERIES EXPANSION STAGE. I CAN'T DELETE IT AS IT WAS ACCEPTED.** - Karn

Hint:

Let $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=1-\ln(1-x)$.

We know that $f(0)=g(0)=1$.

We need $f(x)\ge g(x)$ so if $f(x)-g(x)$ is positive and decreasing then our proof is done. You may want to consider the Taylor expansion to help with the proof.

Following this is the full solution but I suggest you do not look at it until you have attempted it yourself.

> We have $f'(x)=e^x$ and $g'(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$.\begin{align}f'(x)-g'(x)&=e^x-\frac{1}{1-x}\\&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty{\frac{x^r}{r!}}-\sum_{r=0}^\infty{x^r}\\&<0\end{align}

Comment: This is not an answer. This is better to be as a comment.

Comment: @TRUSKI Look at it again. I cannot find the spoiler tag that's why I left a large part out initially.

Comment: This gave me what I needed to solve the problem, I appreciate your time!

Comment: where is the taylor series for $1/(1-x)$ valid?

Comment: @qbert Oh yah. My bad. I'll edit. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Define 
$$
f(x)=e^x-1+\ln(1-x)
$$
where we hope to show $f(x)\geq 0$ for $x\leq 0$. Note that at $x=0$ we have 
$$
f(0)=1-1=0
$$
And we have that 
$$
f'(x)=e^x-\frac{1}{1-x}
$$
where we note that 
$$
f'(x)=e^x-\frac{1}{1-x}\leq 0\iff e^x\leq \frac{1}{1-x}\stackrel{x\leq 0}{\iff} e^{-x}\geq1-x
$$
a well known equality derived from the mean value theorem or visual obvious-ness. Thus your function is decreasing to $0$ on the left of the $y$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y:=-x;$

Then $e^{-y} \ge 1- \ln(1+y)$ , $y\ge 0.$

$f(y) := e^{-y} +\ln(1+y) -1.$

$f(0)= 0.$

$f'(y) = - e^{-y} + \dfrac{1}{1+y};$

$f'(0)=0$.

Need to show that $f'(y) > 0,$ for $y \gt 0,$

which  implies $f(y)$ increasing.

$f'(y) = e^{-y}(\dfrac {e^y}{1+y} -1).$

(Note : $e^{-y} >0$)

$e^y = 1+ y +y^2/2! + ...$

$\dfrac{e^y}{1+y} \gt 1$ for $y>0.$

Hence $f'(y) \gt 0 $, and hence $f(y) >0$.